# Ansible run always role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

Is there any way to always run a role?  I am creating lock file before starting 
 any deployment to prevent parallel deployment. In case of any failure/success I 
 want to delete the lock file.

```
- { role: lock-deployment, tags: always }
- { role: fetch-artifactory, tags: always }
- { role: unlock-deployment, tags: always }
```

I want to run unlock-deployment role irrespective of failure/success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> problem is I don't want to do block, rescue for every task. I just want to delete lock file in case of failure in any of the task. I tried looking around if role itself can be put into block but didn't find any. <sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575257/ansible-run-always-role#comment82109526_47576012)</sup>

You **can** use `block` with `always` construct. Roles can be included with [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_role_module.html):

```
tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: lock-deployment
  - block:
    - include_role:
        name: fetch-artifactory
    always:
      - include_role:
          name: unlock-deployment
```

This produces your desired flow (`fetch-artifactory` contains `fail` task to emulate failure):

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************

TASK [include_role] ************************************************************************************

TASK [lock-deployment : file] **************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [include_role] ************************************************************************************

TASK [fetch-artifactory : fail] ************************************************************************
Unaltered: {'msg': u'Failed as requested from task', 'failed': True, 'changed': False}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed as requested from task"}

TASK [include_role] ************************************************************************************

TASK [unlock-deployment : file] **********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
```

Comment: Thanks @techraf. I would try out this solution and would update  the findings soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ansible **block** and **always** for this situation

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_blocks.html

Comment: problem is I don't want to do block, rescue for every task. I just want to delete lock file in case of failure in any of the task. I tried looking around if role itself can be put into block but didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `block` and including the yaml file from the role instead of declaring the role as a dependency:

```
tasks:
  - name: "start deployment"
    block:
      - include: "<path to roles>/lock-deployment/tasks/main.yaml"
      - include: "<path to roles>/fetch-artifactory/tasks/main.yaml"
      - include: "<path to roles>/unlock-deployment/tasks/main.yaml"
    always:
      - name: "remove lock file"
        ...
```

If you need to include `default` variables from your `roles` you could do:

```
roles:
  - { role: lock-deployment,
      when: False
    }
```

My solution is not an elegant one, but I would really suggest moving off from `roles` for those kind of actions and do `includes` instead.

Also: I have not tested the solution and might not work actually. But it gives an idea to alternate solutions.

Comment: Thanks tehmoon. I am very new to ansible, so trying out various solutions for the problem at hand. I would try this soltion as well and pick whichever makes sense.