# Execute role in play based on a failure

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook that configures a RHEL system and when a host fails for any reason I want to execute a sosreport on the host, without having to run another playbook command. This is different than the question asked here [How to continue execution on failed task after fixing error in playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900096/how-to-continue-execution-on-failed-task-after-fixing-error-in-playbook)
. In that they need to manually continue the playbook. I just want to handle errors during the play.

I'm not quite sure how to express that in the playbook. Is there a magic variable I can use to determine if a play failed to create a playbook similar to below?

```
- hosts: rhel7_64Guest
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: selinux
      tags: selinux

    - role: timezone
      tags: timezone

    - role: dns
      tags: dns

    - role: sosreport
      when: ansible_hosts_failed
      tags:
        - sosreport
        - always
```

Comment: There is [a whole chapter on this in Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html). This is too broad for SO.　Also: roles are collections of tasks, they don't fail.

Comment: I do not agree that it is to broad, maybe I need to phrase my question better. I read that doc and there is nothing there that answers my question. I want to know the status of the overall play so I can take some actions. Very similar to the rescue in a block statement but for entire plays.

Comment: You might also [ask for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594064) (you ask "*if a play failed*", but the example suggests roles). That also does not handle when host connection fails.